# Not receiving notifications from iOS device after subscribed to orion context broker

Tags: fiware-orion

I have set up a server with a port on iOS device, and programatically subscribed to a context broker like this:

```
{
  "notifyConditions": [
    {
      "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL",
      "condValues": [
        "PT10s"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "reference": "http://myipaddress:1028/",
  "entities": [
    {
      "type": "Warning",
      "id": "NotMatch",
      "isPattern": "false"
    }
  ],
  "attributes": [
    "difference"
  ],
  "duration": "P1M"
}
```

and got a response like this:

```
{
  subscribeResponse = {
    duration = P1M;
    subscriptionId = 54b019b9a85d634562fd252f;
  };
}
```

But I cannot receive any notification of the event. If I put the reference as: 
`"reference": "http://localhost:1028/accumulate"`,  I can see the event message on the accumulator-server.py screen.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get notifications locally (i.e. in the same host where Orion is running) using the accumulator-server.py uses to mean that Orion is working fine sending notifications. Thus, probably the problem is related with the network in some sense.

Ensure there is network connectivity from the host where Orion is running to the iOS device receiving notifications (in particular to port 1028) and that no firewall (either running on the iOS device or in some intermediate network element) is filtering that traffic out. You can check network connectivity using for example the `telnet` command from the host where CB is running:

```
telnet myipaddress 1028
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps me find out that the subscription is not useful as I thought in this case. I thought I could get the event notification from my mobile device whenever there is change. But if my device does not have a public ip address, the context broker cannot send any notification to my mobile device.